# При вставке &lt;t size='0.6'&gt; и &lt;/t&gt;" в xml добавляет &amp

Tags: c#, xml

```
el.Add(new XElement("Russian", "&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;" + TranslateText + "&lt;/t&gt;"));
```

Результат:

```html
<Russian>&amp;lt;t size='0.6'&amp;gt;.....&amp;lt;/t&amp;gt;</Russian>
```

Как мне это можно исправить? (Убрать amp)

Comment: &amp - на сколько я знаю, это и есть экранированный знак &, вам надо сделать следующее:

`el.Add(new XElement("Russian", "<t size='0.6'>" + TranslateText + "</t>"));` по идее проблема должна быть решена, но вот парсить и собирать XML, это уже в прошлом веке осталось, смотрите в сторону xml сериализации!

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, какой вы в итоге хотите вариант?
 <Russian>&lt;t size='0.6'&amp;gt;.....&amp;lt;/t&gt;</Russian> ? Если так, то
 el.Add(new XElement("Russian", "&amp;lt;t size='0.6'&gt;" + TranslateText + "&amp;lt;/t&gt;"));

Comment: Здравствуйте, я хотел бы вариант без &amp;

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы в конечном итоге было как здесь: &lt;t size='0.6'&gt;" + TranslateText + "&lt;/t&gt;"

Comment: el.Add(new XElement("Russian", "<t size='0.6'>" + TranslateText + "</t>")); помогло. Спасибо